# Position Elements in CSS3

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a simple layout with HTML5 + CSS3 as pictured below, for a high school job, however, I'm not aware of programming and I'm having difficulty with placements in CSS3, this is the codepen I'm doing, and that's the layout image how do I need to stay, can you help me?

Thank you =)

```
My Codepen:
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/omineiro/pen/qgvxPR)

Layout Image: [Image on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1YTe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## General tips and tricks

you can easily centre elements by using:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

If you don't have too many elements, you can try using float, e.g.:

```
float: left;
```

I see you are using a lot of pixel positioning and not % or vw (view width) or vh (view height). That is fine for a small project, you could set the position to relative and then add margins (note that margins can be negavite to position objects even further, e.g.:

```
position: relative;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 50px;
```

---

## A few examples using your code

You can for example center you button with:

```
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Or you could position an image to the right using:

```
header > div > img {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

---

A great site to learn HTML, CSS and Javascript and could be a great reference for you is [htmldog.com](https://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/). It's free!

Comment: Hi Robert,

Thank you very much for showing me this site, I'm going to study. =)